# What should WSO2 APIM <localMemberHost> parameter contain in the config and what it is used by the APIM?

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to deploy APIM in a distributed setup with docker. What should be the value of localmemberhost value in the axis2.xml file? And what it is used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used for clustering. If you use WKA membership schema you need to specify your IP address of the container which accessible from outside. For docker, this is the docker contain IP.

Comment: We are using AWS membership scheme in this. For what purpose will this be used by APIM?

Comment: This is used for clustering. The value comes under localMemberHost is shared among the other members. This will be used by other members to connect to other nodes. This is also used in AWS as well.